# real time traffic api

Tags: java, api, opendata

Is there an API that lets me know of real-time traffic in an area/city/location?

I don't have any location in mind, but it is OK to have access to an API that restricts the access of traffic to a particular location.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean general car traffic - don't know any I'm afraid - there are APIs for things like live bus arrival times though - see this one for Ottowa: http://www.octranspo1.com/developers